# Javascript Random Number generate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to generate random number between 0 to 100 and show a `div` tag if that random isn't less than 10. I have this code but it doesn't work, please can you help me fix the error.

I have already tried on google but I can not find code for php

```js
function showbox(){
    document.getElementById("ap1").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function myFunction(name) {
    var x = document.getElementById("demo")
    x.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
}

if(myFunction(<=10){
    setTimeout(showbox, 35000);
}
```

```html
<div id="ap1" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
```

Comment: Check the console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <=`

Answer (score 1):

Your code has `SyntaxError`. You can use this code

```js
var element = document.getElementById("ap1");
var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
element.innerHTML = random;

if (random >= 10){
    document.getElementById("ap1").style.visibility = "visible";   
} else
  console.log(random);
```

```html
<div id="ap1" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
```

`Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)` generate number between `1 and 100`. If you want to generate number between `0 and 100` use `Math.floor((Math.random() * 101))` or `Math.round((Math.random() * 100))`

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/myrluk3/urw6pp3g/2/). The code wasn't correct. You used `demo` id but you have `ap1`, and the `if` condition also was wrong in JavaScript.

The JavaScript code:

```
function myFunction(name) {
  var x = document.getElementById("ap1")
  var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  if (randomNum > 10) {
    x.innerHTML = randomNum;
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = 'empty';
  }
}

setTimeout(myFunction, 350);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to close `myFunction` in the `if` and you need to `return` in `myFunction`:-

```js
function showbox(){
    document.getElementById("ap1").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function myFunction(name) {
    var x = document.getElementById("ap1")
    return x.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
}

if(myFunction() <= 10){
    setTimeout(showbox, 35000);
}
```

```html
<div id="ap1" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
```